# Can't pass slug variable correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql

Can't seam to pass slug variable correctly. When i try to my component dose not render.
I changed the slug: in Post.js and :slug in App.js to a maching string for testing and only then i get the Post.js component rendered.

I seams to me that im not passing the slug variable right.

**App.js**

```
const App = () => (
<Router>
  <Header />
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route path=":slug" component={Post} />
  </Switch>
</Router>
);
export default App;
```

**Post.js**

```
 const Post = (slug) => (
  <Query query={singlePost} variables={{slug: slug.match.params.urlPath}}>
    {({ loading, error, data }) => {
      if (loading || !data) return <h2>Loading post...</h2>
      if (error) return <h1>Error fetching the post!</h1>
      return (
      <article>
        <h1>{data.articles[0].title}</h1>
      </article>
      )
    }}
  </Query>
)

export const singlePost = gql`
  query singlePost($slug: String!) {
    articles(search: $slug) {
      title
      urlPath
      owner {
        username
      }
    }
  }
`

export default Post;
```

Comment: Have you tried to add a slash at the beginning of the dynamic route?

`<Route path="/:slug" component={Post} />`

Comment: @David Thanks for noticing. But that did not fix the problem, i cant get values dynamically only if i pass slug as a string like this `variables={{slug: "/home/new-post/"}}` and go to that url.

Comment: I changed `slug.match.params.urlPath` to `slug.location.pathname` and now it works ok. is this a good approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add a `*` on the rout path 
`<Route path="/:slug*" component={Post} />`

The slug it self contains forward slashes example `/new/test/` with out it match.params.slug returned just the `/new` part of the slug with `*` it brakes out of the any forward slashes.